# this->getAddToWishlistUrl is https vs. http and this causes conflict - how to change

Tags: wishlist, magento-1.4

Our e-commerce site runs non-secure (http) for all pages except essential pages such as checkout process pages.

I have some custom coding in a view.phtml file which a user clicks to add an item to their wishlist.  The line that I'm referencing is as follows:

```
mageglobal.product['saveToWishlistUrl']="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>";
```

which spits out an `https` URL, even though my current browser url is `http`.  My question is, how can I change core config data or settings so that this method call will mirror the current page's state (or i.e. the state of the page when the script was called)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that `getAddToWishlistUrl` takes any arguments other than an instance of the product.

```
 public function getAddToWishlistUrl($product)
```

See https://github.com/sonassi/magento-ce/blob/b4e6732185c132b760e58b472cb8dfea6dd26270/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Compare/List.php#L78